# Split line to words of maximum size of 8 characters

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting

I'm creating script that will display 2 times the song name in FM radio station name. Radio station name is limited to 8 characters. Lets say I have this line: `Best Direction - I feel good`

The code will look like this: (the "PS" is start of line software know it's command to change name)

```
echo "PS Best" > $fifo;
sleep 1;
echo "PS Directio" > $fifo;
sleep 1;
echo "PS n - I" > $fifo;
sleep 1;
echo "PS feel" > $fifo;
sleep 1;
echo "PS good" > $fifo;
sleep 1;
//repeat this one more time
```

How to do that in bash script? I have no idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `fold` from [GNU Core Utilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Core_Utilities):

```
a="Best Direction - I feel good"
fold -s -w 8 <<< "$a" | while read -r line; do 
  echo "PS $line" > "$fifo"
 sleep 1
done
```

Output to $fifo:

```
PS Best
PS Directio
PS n - I
PS feel
PS good
```

Without `fold` with same output to $fifo:

```
a="Best Direction - I feel good"
while [[ -n $a ]]; do     # loop until $a is empty
  if [[ ${#a} -gt 8 ]]; then
    b="${a:0:8}"          # get first 8 characters of $a
    c="${b% *}"           # crop all from right incl. first whitespace
  else
    c="$a"
  fi
  echo "PS $c" > "$fifo"
  d="${a#$c}"             # crop $c left from string $a
  a="${d# *}"             # remove a leading whitespace
  sleep 1
done
```

Comment: It giving me error `Syntax error: redirection unexpected`. Maybe its because I have the update code part in: `while true; do; sleep 1; done` to run the update again and again forever.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot so specifi /bin/bash :D

Comment: Now it works perfectly!

Comment: Note that GNU `fold` only works with single-byte characters. Won't work properly with UTF-8 like in `fold -s -w 8 <<< "La grande traversée"`. Then again, we don't know what charset is expected at the other end of that fifo, or if 8 is the number of characters or the display width of the string.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: Thanks for the useful note. I agree with you.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas well that doesn't matter, because RDS name not support that as well.